# Какое значение может иметь текстовый контент элемента style в спецификации HTML5?

Tags: css, html5, style

[В спецификации](https://www.w3.org/TR/2014/PR-html5-20140916/document-metadata.html#the-style-element) написано следующее

> The textContent of a style element must match the style production in
>   the following ABNF, the character set for which is Unicode.

```
style         = no-c-start *( c-start no-c-end c-end no-c-start )
no-c-start    = < any string that doesn't contain a substring that matches c-start >
c-start       = "<!--"
no-c-end      = < any string that doesn't contain a substring that matches c-end >
c-end         = "-->"
```

Не могу понять, что там написано. Вроде как, что содержимое style должно быть следующим... А каким, не пойму. Что за `no-c-start *( c-start no-c-end)` и т.д.? Что это означает? Как понимать вообще?

Answer (score 2):

[Augmented Backus–Naur Form](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/std/std68.txt) — [расширенная форма Бэкуса-Наура](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0_%D0%91%D1%8D%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%81%D0%B0_%E2%80%94_%D0%9D%D0%B0%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0), формальный язык спецификации сетевых протоколов и синтаксиса языков программирования. Использует регулярные выражения, подобные тем, которыми разбирают строки в пхп или яваскрипте.

- скобки - это группировка элементов
- звёздочка перед скобкой означает, что эта группировка может повторяться ноль или более раз
- no-c-start - любая строка, не содержащая начало комментария
- no-c-end - любая строка, не содержащая окончание комментария

Таким образом, формула обобщает правила про хтмл-комментарии внутри тега `<style></style>`. Я понимаю её так:

> 1. Окончание комментария может идти первым (но его примут за обычный текст).
> 2. Может идти несколько начал комментария подряд (на за настоящий комментарий посчитают только первое из них).
> 3. Cодержимое тега не должно заканчиваться незакрытым комментарием.